# Hosting react web app on FireBase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, deployment, firebase-hosting

I've built a reactJs web app and I'm trying to deploy it on fire base. 
I did all the steps on out the `index.js` file inside the `Public` folder that firebase created and I get `404` page. What should I do ? Thanks!!

**src/index.js :**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import firebase from 'firebase'


import App from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);

var config = {
  apiKey: "XXXXXX",
  authDomain: "forecast-34204.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://forecast-34204.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "forecast-34204",
  storageBucket: "forecast-34204.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "352834183798"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

**Files:**

[image: Files]

Comment: No I used this: https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter

Comment: I'm kind of new with this. How I'm suppose to create such script? Thank!